# Getting entries from relationship and sub-relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have three tables `foo`, `bar` and `lorem`. They are connected to each other with Many-To-Many relationships.

How can I efficiently get all entries of `lorem` where `foo.id` is `123`, both directly and through `bar` (without duplicates) ?

#### === EDIT ===

Schema:

```
Foo -> Lorem          |
                      |----- MERGE
Foo -> Bar -> Lorem   |
```

I'm currently doing it this way:

```
# Get lorems from foos
$loremsA = Foo::find(123)->lorems()->get();

# Get ids of bars for given foo:
$bar_ids = Foo::find(123)->bars()->pluck('id')->toArray();
# Get lorems from bars
$loremsB = Lorem::whereHas('bars', fn($q) => $q->whereIn('id', $bar_ids))->get();

# Merge
$loremsB->merge($loremsA)
```

Is there any better way to do it ?

Comment: Your question is bit short and ambiguous, or at least for me. Can you explain it a little more?

Comment: @AhmadKarimi I've just updated my post to make it less ambiguous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse-querying should work for you. Directly query the `Lorem` model, and check for reverse-relationship existence:

```php
Lorem::whereHas('bars', function($query) {
  $query->whereHas('foos', function($subQuery) {
    $subQuery->where('foos.id', 123);
  })
})->get();
```

If `Lorem` can alternatively be directly related to `Foo`, then you can do an `orWhereHas()`:

```php
Lorem::whereHas('bars', function($query) {
  $query->whereHas('foos', function($subQuery) {
    $subQuery->where('foos.id', 123);
  })
})->orWhereHas('foos', function($query){ 
  $query->where('foos.id', 123);
})->get();
```

That should return all `Lorem` models that belong to a `Bar` that belongs to `Foo`, or that directly belongs to `Foo`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I'm getting `Syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ')'` on both queries whatever I try.

Comment: Woops, missed  a closing `)`, 1 sec;

Comment: A `;` is also missing ;-) Thanks a lot, impressive.

Comment: Sorry, seems my typing is off today; and I've been swapping between languages a lot, most of which don't expressly need the `;`. Happy to help either way, cheers!

Comment: `Lorem` is also directly related to `Foo`, is the second query faster in such case ?

Comment: As long as they're linked by ids and indexed properly, both queries should be pretty quick. Laravel relationships aren't the most optimal queries sometimes, and there's libraries to adjust how the joins are done behind the scenes, but you'd have to do some research and profiling to see if their use is necessary.